# Disable root for a group

Tags: sudo, root, groups

I have a server and I would like to have it where a group called client can't access sudo/su/root. How do I do that? I know to use the visudo command.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about why the members of the 'client' group *can* access root privileges in the first place.

As far as `sudo` is concerned, those user's privileges are defined in the sudoers file, that you can edit with `visudo` (provided you have the neccessary privileges yourself). The sudoers file can be seen as a whitelist: Only those privileges defined in the sudoers file are granted.

So you'd have to check which part of your current sudoers file grants users in the group 'client' `sudo` privileges, and then revoke or rework those. But be careful, it's easy to lock yourself out if you're revoking to much ;)

As far as `su` is concerned, to use that command to gain root privileges a user needs to know the root account's credentials (e. g. its password). If your 'client' user know your server's root password, there's only one thing you can do: Change the root password, and never tell it anybody who doesn't positively *has* to know it again ;)

Comment: Or even better, disable the root password again as it is by default on Ubuntu. That way you can control root access completely through the configuration of `sudo` and policy kit.